# vector error while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

this a program I made , and I'm new at C++ (start yesterday) ,the program is suppose to draw a polynomial function by taking the function in a string form from the user and draw it using "ccc_win.h" library but
every time i try to compile the program this message appear :

Debug Assertion Failed !!

Expression : vector subscript out of range

I don't know what the problem is , can u help me please .

```
#include "ccc_win.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int ccc_win_main()
{
    vector <double> coefficient;
    vector <double> power;


    string input = cwin.get_string("enter the equation >>");
    int length = input.length();
    int i = 0;
    while (i <length)
    {
        if (input[i] == '=' || input[i] == '+' || input[i] == '-')
        {
            string c;
            int j = i + 1;
            while (input[j] != '(')
            {
                c += input[j];
                j += 1;
            }
            double c_double = ::atof(c.c_str());
            coefficient.push_back(c_double);

        }

        else if (input[i] == '^')
        {
            string p;
            int j = i + 1;
            while (input[j] != ')')
            {
                p += input[j];
                j += 1;
            }

            double p_double = ::atof(p.c_str());
            power.push_back(p_double);

        }

        i++;
    }

    cwin << Line(Point(0, -10), Point(0, 10)) << Line(Point(-10, 0), Point(10, 0));
    double x = 0, y = 0;
    for (x = 10; x <= 10; x += 0.001)

    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
        {


            y += (coefficient[i] * pow(x, power[i]));
        }

        Point a(x, y);
        cwin << a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: debug yourself more times please!

Comment: Use the debugger. Figure out what line causes the crash, what the vector's size is, and what the index you give it is.

Comment: In the final for loop you are using the variable i, which will be the length of the expression that you entered. I guess, that's not what you want to be there exactly.

Comment: when I debug it shows the "y+= (coefficient[i] * pow(x,power[i])); "
is the problem , but I still don't know how to fix it 

Ps: sorry for being late I have some connection problems :)

Comment: Out of bounds access to `power[i]` most probably, check `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `int j = i + 1;` For *i* pointing to the last element, j will point outside the array. You need to check if `j < length` as well, after setting it

Also here:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= 10; k++)
{
    y += (coefficient[i] * pow(x, power[i]));
}
```

You're looping through k but using i as coefficient. But i == length at that point, because the previous loop incremented it and finished when i == length.
Are you sure you don't want `k` instead of `i` in the loop above? `i` most certainly has an incorrect value at that point.